# Azure pipeline build number as NuGet package version number

Tags: azure-pipelines

I have an Azure build pipeline that I want to use to make a NuGet package.

The `.csproj` has

```
VersionPrefix>1.2.0</VersionPrefix>
```

and I want the version of the NuGet to:

- have a dot the build number appended to it, and
- have a hyphen then the branch name appended if the branch is not `master` (and thus produce a pre-release package).
  Thus package versions could be: `1.2.0.8`, `1.2.1-hotfix20210525`, `1.2.1`,...

In the pileline `yml` I have:

```
  ${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'master') }}:
    buildConfiguration: 'Release'
    tag: ''
    
  ${{ if ne(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'master') }}:
    buildConfiguration: 'Debug'
    tag: ${{ format('-{0}', variables['Build.SourceBranchName']) }}

...

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet pack Filename'
  inputs:
    command: 'pack'
    packagesToPack: 'Folder/Filename.csproj'
    includesymbols: true
    includesource: true
    nobuild: true
    buildProperties: 'VersionSuffix="$(Build.BuildId)$(tag)"'
    versionSuffix: '$(Build.BuildId)$(tag)'
    outputDir: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    arguments: '--version-suffix $(Build.BuildId)$(tag)'
```

But this doesn't work because *versionb suffix* means the suff what goes after the hyphen and thus all of my packages appear to be pre-release.

Can this be made to work -- using the build number as part of the version number and *only* the `tag` as the prerelease name?

** EDIT: Assign the required value to a varialbe **

I tried to make the required version number with the idea of specifying it in full to the `pack` command. But of course it doesn't work.

```
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
         $xml = [Xml] (Get-Content Folder\Filename.csproj)
         $versionPrefix = $xml.Project.PropertyGroup.VersionPrefix
         echo $versionPrefix
         $version = $($versionPrefix).$(Build.BuildId)$(tag)
         echo "ECHO"
         echo $version
         echo $(version)
```

```
========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
##[debug]Entering Invoke-VstsTool.
##[debug] Arguments: '-NoLogo -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command ". 'C:\agent\_work\_temp\fa4b86cc-c5a4-41f8-b6b8-a90492732482.ps1'"'
##[debug] FileName: 'C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe'
##[debug] WorkingDirectory: 'C:\agent\_work\12\s'
##[command]"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoLogo -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command ". 'C:\agent\_work\_temp\fa4b86cc-c5a4-41f8-b6b8-a90492732482.ps1'"
At C:\agent\_work\_temp\fa4b86cc-c5a4-41f8-b6b8-a90492732482.ps1:5 char:35
+ $version = $($versionPrefix).10504-pipeline
+                                   ~~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token '-pipeline' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
 
##[debug]Exit code: 1
##[debug]Leaving Invoke-VstsTool.
##[error]PowerShell exited with code '1'.
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that it would be not possible to set via `version-prefix` and you need to provide full packageversion

```yaml
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: "dotnet pack"
  inputs:
    command: custom
    custom: pack
    arguments: >
      Folder/Filename.csproj
      --no-build
      -p:PackageId=myId
      --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
      -p:PackageVersion=2.1.0$(tag)
      -p:Configuration=$(buildConfiguration)
    packagesToPack: '**/*.csproj'
    versioningScheme: 'off'
    outputDir: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
```

However in this case you need to first fetch currect value of `VersionPrefix` from csproj.